# Refresh page and keeping scroll position

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a table that's generated by a foreach loop and I'm trying to make it so when a user refreshes the screen it takes them to the same position on the page after the refresh. The code for my table is below:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Scanned</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        // Generate the picking table
        foreach($picking_list as $product){

            $product_name = $product['name'];

            echo "<tr><td>";
            echo $product_name;
            if(!empty($product['barcode'])){
                echo "<span>Barcode: " . $product['barcode'] . "</span>";
            } else {
                echo '<span id="red_text"><strong><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Warning! Barcode missing! Please confirm stock manually.<strong></span>';
            }
            echo '</td><td id="scan_count">';
            echo $product['scanned'] . '/' . $product['quantity'];
            // Mark as scanned button. Popup confirmation and form submit
            echo '<form onsubmit="return confirm(\'Do you want to mark all ' . $tools->cleanHyphens($product_name) . ' as scanned?\');" action="" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="scan_all">
            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="' . $product['product_id'] . '">
            <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Confirm All">
            </form>';
            echo "</tr>";

        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Some background for this, this is a program that generates a picking list for warehouse staff, they scan the product barcode it compares it to there order and confirms if it's the correct item and the users have fed back that after they scan a barcode and the page refreshes they want to be in the same scroll position.

Comment: Have you considered using AJAX for this? This would go out and retrieve the data and reload the section not the entire page. As for reloading the page and keeping the scroll position a cookie could do this if you were so inclined to set one. Hope this helps.

Comment: I recommend looking into the browser's `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` properties to persist `document.documentElement.scrollTop`. Then on the next page load, if the persisted data exists, set `document.documentElement.scrollTop` equal to that value. (Or as the previous comment suggests, look into methods to not refreshing the page).

Comment: Please do not change old questions to completely new questions - they may be linked from other questions, there are comments and they're indexed by search engines. The question you edited it to is better suited for the Software Engineering site: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See these highly relevant tags on Software Engineering: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planning?tab=Votes and https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-management?tab=Votes - Good terms for searching would be agile project planning and software like kanban boards (Trello for example). But please stop creating unnecessary work by completely changing your questions.